# Extjs localstore method set

Tags: extjs

I am not able to update record in localStorage by id. I get the exception :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined WebStorage.js:391Ext.define.getIds WebStorage.js:391Ext.define.update WebStorage.js:190Ext.define.runOperation Batch.js?_dc=1423751003307:251Ext.define.start Batch.js?_dc=1423751003307:178Ext.define.batch Proxy.js?_dc=1423751002203:456Ext.define.sync AbstractStore.js?_dc=1423751002173:810Ext.define.afterEdit AbstractStore.js?_dc=1423751002173:906Ext.define.callStore Model.js?_dc=1423751003310:1814Ext.define.afterEdit Model.js?_dc=1423751003310:1773Ext.define.set Model.js?_dc=1423751003310:1175(anonymous function) Main.js?_dc=1423751002786:26(anonymous function) VM3763:6wrap

My model is simple:

```
Ext.define('AM.model.Points', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: {
          name: 'UUID', 
          type: String,
          isUnique: true
        },  
    fields: [ 
              {
                name: 'NO',
                type: "string"
              },
              {
                name: 'Y',
                type: "int"
              },
              {
                name: 'ROW',
                type: 'int'
              },
              {
                name: 'SEAT',
                type: 'string'
              },

              {
                name: 'PROCEEDED',
                type: 'int'
              },
              {
                name: 'X',
                type: "int"
              },
              {
                name: "CurrentPlace",
                type: "int",  
                defaultValue: 0  
              }
              ],

});
```

My controller class init function:

```
init: function(){
        // метод getStore контроллера возвращает экземпляр хранилища,
        // если он уже создан - или создаёт его 
    console.log('Main controller init function()');

    var changingImage = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
        src: '/is-bin/intershop.static/WFS/EnterpriseOrg-MainChannel-Site/ProductStore/ru_RU/kzch.jpg',
        renderTo: Ext.get('canv1')
    });
     Ext.get('canv1').on('click', function(eventObj, elRef) {
         var index = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("LocalStore").findExact('UUID',AM.util.Utilities.CurrentPlace);
         var rec = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("LocalStore").getAt(index);
         console.log('Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("LocalStore") ' +  Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("LocalStore"));
         console.log('index' + index);
         console.log('rec' + rec);
         var uuid = rec.get('UUID');
         console.log('uuid is: '+uuid);
        **rec.set('X', window.event.offsetX);**
    });
```

The logic is that I click on canvas and pass X coordinate of the click to method on click. I retrieve model from store by previously saved id to update it. But I cant update record. What should be done? Version 4.2.1 Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can grab the "X" coordinate from the Ext EventObject in the funciton
`eventObj.getX()`

Comment: Post pleas your proxy configuration and also the code that tries to update the model.

Comment: Ext.define('AM.store.LocalStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires  : ['AM.model.Points', 'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],
    model: "AM.model.Points",

    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id  : 'Names'
    }
});

Comment: I update the store without applying to model - just find record and try to set value to it.

Comment: I debugged to the point of exception:  getIds: function() {
        var me = this,
            ids = (me.getStorageObject().getItem(me.id) || "").split(","),
            model = me.model,
            length = ids.length,
            isString = model.prototype.fields.get(model.prototype.idProperty).type.type === 'string',
            i;

        if (length == 1 && ids[0] === "") {
            ids = [];
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                ids[i] = isString ? ids[i] : +ids[i];
            }
        } - Here model is undefined

Comment: So maybe I should create model object when trying to update local store? I supposed that method var rec = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup("LocalStore").getAt(index) would do it implicitly.